# Forwarding a static website using Docker

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, docker, port-forwarding

I have a website serving static HTML/client-side JS, running on a machine on my LAN. The website is accessible from *192.168.0.10:81*, and there is no DNS.

I have another machine on the LAN which serves a number of internet-facing websites. These are accessible from *192.168.0.11:81-82*, with each address having a DNS record. Each website exists in a Docker container, the the [jwilder/nginx reverse proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) is used to map DNS to port addresses.

Is it possible to have a Docker container on the second machine *192.168.0.11:83*, which serves out static content from *192.168.0.10:81* on the LAN? This would allow setting DNS environment variables from the docker-compose file. Is there a different approach to achieving this? A diagram of this situation:

[image: Network diagram]

Answer (score 0):

On a reverse proxy I would add an record to website to forward specific traffic to machine a.

Or you can create another reverse proxy on machine b to forward traffic to A. But this is over kill, because of a same subnet of machine A, B and reverse proxy.